# htaccess to web.config 500 internal server error

Tags: .htaccess, web-config

I have web page working on a linux server.
This is the content of htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  index.php?sayfa=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I moved my page to a windows server which supports php and mysql. Htaccess did not work. 
I created web.config code using an online tool. 
This is my webconfig code.

```
<rule name="rule 1Q" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^(.*)$"  />
<action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?sayfa={R:1}"  />
</rule>
```

but this code does not work? 
How can i fix it? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: This question has nothing to do with [.htaccess] or [apache], and if you hover over [web-config] you can see that it is not what you thought it would be. Could you please tag the question with the software you are actually having trouble with?

Comment: I dont have any software. I coded my own page. for seo urls I started using this htaccess code. This code gives all url after domain to as sayfa variable, then i explode and show the content. I only want to make same thing by web.config

Comment: Your http deamon is software. What http deamon are you using? What version of it are you using? I am sure there must be an error log in the http deamon you are using. What is written in there when you get an internal server error? If you don't tag your question with the right tags, the chances of someone with enough knowledge stumbling upon it is very slim.